# 2009 Chevy Malibu LTZ No crank but starts on second attempt

Tags: chevrolet, malibu

I have 2009 {Chevy Malibu LTZ} (No crank)but starts on second attempt.

When starting car everything turns on, fuel pump runs and gauges test etc.  Then turning key more to start nothing happening no clicking nothing.  Let up on key try again or turn off/on and it starts just fine.

I tried it today and held it to start took about full 2seconds then started fine. While holding to start it did nothing then after the delay cranked and started like normal.  Usually happens once in morning and will start all day. Hot or cold engine. Happened about a week now my boys drive this car.

I’m wondering if this has happened to others and what the fix is. Want to fix it before it doesn’t start/leaves them stranded somewhere.

NOTE: Asked My son how long has this been going on he did not know because he said he remote starts the car all the time. Puts key in and turns to run when he gets in.

Comment: How many miles on the car? It could be a failing fuel pump, clogged fuel filter on the pump or pump relay.

Comment: what's your fuel pressure ? Is it loosing pressure when the car is just ON, does it fluctuate when you start the car, does the pressure jump 10 psi when you unplug the fuel pressure regulators vacuum, from ON to START does the psi drop ?

Comment: I didn’t know the fuel pressure would prevent the car from cranking.  The car never turns over (aka cranks) when it does turn over it’s starts.  When I say turn over I mean car is running and right now.  So it never cracks and cranks.

Comment: Car started fine this morning, just thought something might be going bad.

Answer (score 1):

**Engine rotates but will not start**

```
Fuel tank is empty

There's water in your fuel

Defective Mass air flow sensor

Wet or damaged Ignition coil(s)

Dirty or clogged fuel Injectors

Faulty or incorrectly gapped spark plugs

Low compression in cylinders - head gasket

Battery Is Discharged - cold cranking amps

Timing chain failure or wear that's affecting the valves

Fuel Is not reaching fuel Injectors - fuel pressure test
```

**Engine will not rotate when attempting to start**

```
Broken, Loose wire in the starting circuit -  battery - starter- Ignition switch (not cylinder)

Automatic transmission not in park or neutral - check Transmission range sensor

Battery terminals loose or corroded

Starter motors pinion is jammed

Battery Discharged or faulty

Starter solenoid is faulty

Ignition switch is faulty

Starter relay is faulty
```

**Engine hard to start when cold**

```
Battery cold cranking amps- acid stratification

Defective coolant temp sensor

Fuel injectors or fuel pressure
```

**Engine hard to start when hot**

```
air filter is dirty

bad engine ground

Fuel injection or engine crank - camshaft sensor
```